# NSight VS Edition - is it included in CUDA 5.0 toolkit and how to use it?

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

Can you please tell me how to start NSight in VS 2010? I have downloaded and installed correctly CUDA toolkit 5.0. Is there any tutorial on how to use NSight and what does it do?

P.S. Is there any book ON CUDA and any CUDA version that doesn't have one million errors?

Comment: There are no errors in any CUDA version and CUDA book. Don't blame if you don't know how to use them.

Comment: @sgar91 Well, [practically no errors](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-example-errata-page), but yeah, you are right about the rest. The OP's problems so far are more than likely not caused by the book he uses.

Comment: Well, for someone like my who enjoys the .NET world, this CUDA setup is terrible, I mean the worst one I came across for many years. So, CUDa as an API is excellent but setup and user resources are not what would one expect from such a widespread concept.

Comment: @Bart...Thanks for the errata link. Well atleast CUDA versions are good enough.

Comment: @AntunTun Then you're really not looking well enough. There are heaps of documentation that come with each release. NSight is pretty clearly documented as well. This all reads more than a rant (certainly before my edit) rather than an actual on-topic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nsight Visual Studio Edition is a separate download. The current version is Nsight 3.0 RC1. The installer can be downloaded for free from NVIDIA Registered Developer Program.

The [Nsight Visual Studio Edition home page](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition) has links to download Nsight as well as links to the User Guide, Getting Started Documents, and Webinars.